# Could private static class Spring bean annotated @Service be autowired?

Tags: java, spring

If I have a private static inner class annotated with `@Service`, will it be autowired?
Will Spring's component search find it?

Comment: Have you tried doing this ?

Comment: Why don't you test this? It's pretty simple.

Comment: Can classes be static?

Comment: By 'autowired': Do you mean that your private static class has beans injected into it - or that your class itself is candidate to be injected into other beans?

Comment: @KevinBowersox yes, inner classes can be `private` and `static`.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox - Only nested (inner) classes can be static.

Comment: @user1902288 I believe `private static` classes can be instantiated with reflection, and compiler itself creates a `package visible` constructor for them.

Comment: @tbsalling The second case.

Comment: I believe, provided that the outer class instantiation is managed by `Spring` then it should be able to detect and inject the inner class. This, however, is just speculation. Go and give it a go and tell us what you find out!

Comment: @Chris: Even if the outer class is instantiated by Spring unless there is some sort of API in that class to allow it no one will have access to its private static inner classes not even to the annotations or other metadata i'd say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; Spring's component scanner will also find inner classes and treat them as beans.

Remember to use the $-notation when referring to the class from an XML-file; e.g.

`<bean id="myBean" class="com.mybeans.OuterClass$InnerClass"/>`.

**UPDATE:** Yes; Spring can instantiate private inner classes.

Comment: PRIVATE inner classes as well?

Comment: Wow... time to take a deep dive into the Spring Framework then :)

Comment: I tested this and it works. I am confused as how spring accesses the "Private" inner class(mind that its a private member of outerclass and can not be accessed directly)?????

Comment: Spring uses reflection, which I believe allows access to private members.